# Using Bash to iterate through nested directories and extract certain fields from YAML files

Tags: bash, yaml

I am learning `bash` and what I need is to iterate through a directory (inside has other directories) and find all files with the name `example.yaml`.

These files have several key-value pairs (example below):

```yaml
name: Andre
age: 13
address: street
weight: 78kgs
```

What I need is inside a certain directory (must include nested directories) using bash commands to find all `example.yaml` files and then, copy only the name and age to a new file. This new file needs to be created and would look like this:

```yaml
persons:
  - name: Andre
    age: 13
  - name: Joao
    age: 18
  ...
```

I was trying to do something like this to solve this problem

```
printf 'persons:\n' > output.yml
for i in $(find ./ -name "example.yaml");
do
 name=$(yq '.name' $i)
 age=$(yq '.age' $i)
 
 // append $name and $age to output.yaml
done
```

Comment: Do you mean all files whose name is `example.yaml`?

Comment: I'd split this: YAML has more than one way to denote such key/value pairs, and parsing it using bash and generic regular expression tools is an explicitly bad idea. So, don't. Bash isn't the right tool, and a good carpenter knows that his chisel is not what a masonry needs.

Comment: Not telling you much new, but ```shopt -s globstar; for yamlfile in **/example.yaml; do some_specific_yamltool --options "${yamlfile}"; done``` solves your iterate through all files; and `some_specific_yamltool` should probably be `yq`, which is meant for *exactly* this kind of operation.

Comment: Hmm... you just added something to the required output that does not seem to be part of the input without explaining it further.  If you have further questions about processing YAML, then consider asking a new question instead of modifying the requirements of this already answered question.  I'm reverting your edit as it severely alters the question.

Comment: ok, @Kusalananda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: The length of this answer is due to the fact that there are at least two major variants of utilities called `yq`, made for parsing YAML data, with slightly different abilities and expression grammar, and I cover both.  I also look at simply using filename globbing to find all files *and* using `find` (when there simply are too many input files).  Finally, I address additional questions asked in the comments.

---

Don't iterate over the output of `find`.  Instead, call your utility from `find` using `-exec`.  I have an example of this further down in this answer.  You also lack quoting of some expansions.

See also:

- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)
- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)

---

Given one or several YAML files on the command line, the following `yq` command would create the YAML data summary file:

```bash
yq -y -s '{ persons: map({ name: .name, age: .age }) }' files
```

The command reads all input into a large array (thanks to `-s`, or `--slurp`) which is then passed to the `map()` command.  The `map()` command extracts the `name` and `age` fields of each element in the array and adds these as an object to the `persons` array.

This uses Andrey Kislyuk's Python-based `yq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/, a wrapper around the versatile JSON parser `jq`.  If you drop the `-y` option from the command, you'll get JSON output instead.

Using Mike Farah's Go-based `yq` instead:

```bash
yq -N '[{ "name": .name, "age": .age }]' files | yq '{ "persons": . }'
```

In the `bash` shell, you would apply this to all `example.yaml` files in the current directory or anywhere below it, creating the output file `output.yaml` in the current directory, like so:

```bash
shopt -s globstar failglob

yq -y -s '{ persons: map({ name: .name, age: .age }) }' ./**/example.yaml >output.yaml
```

Or, with Mike Farah's `yq`:

```bash
shopt -s globstar failglob

yq -N '[{ "name": .name, "age": .age }]' ./**/example.yaml | yq '{ "persons": . }' >output.yaml
```

This assumes that there are fewer than a few thousand `example.yaml` files, or the command line would expand to a too long command.

The `globstar` shell option is first enabled to allow us to use the `**` filename globbing pattern, which matches across `/` in pathnames.  We also enable the `failglob` shell option to make the whole command fail gracefully if there are no matching filenames.

Testing:

```bash
$ tree
.
├── dir1
│   └── example.yaml
├── example.yaml
└── script-andrey
└── script-mike

1 directory, 4 files
```

```bash
$ cat script-andrey
shopt -s globstar failglob
yq -y -s '{ persons: map({ name: .name, age: .age }) }' ./**/example.yaml >output.yaml
```

```bash
$ bash script-andrey
$ cat output.yaml
persons:
  - name: Joao
    age: 18
  - name: Andre
    age: 13
```

Testing Mikes `yq` as well:

```bash
$ cat script-mike
shopt -s globstar failglob
yq -N '[{ "name": .name, "age": .age }]' ./**/example.yaml | yq '{ "persons": . }' >output.yaml
```

```bash
$ bash script-mike
$ cat output.yaml
persons:
  - name: Joao
    age: 18
  - name: Andre
    age: 13
```

---

If you have many many thousands of these YAML input files, then you may want to apply `yq` a bit smarter, using `find`.

This is using Andrey's `yq`:

```bash
find . -name example.yaml -type f \
    -exec yq -y -s 'map({ name: .name, age: .age })' {} + |
yq -y '{ persons: . }' >output.yaml
```

This finds all regular files whose name is `example.yaml`.  These are passed in batches to `yq` which will extract the `name` and `age` fields from each, creating an array.  There is then a final `yq` command that collects the generated YAML array and places it as the value of the `persons` key in the final output.

Similarly, with Mike's `yq`:

```bash
find . -name example.yaml -type f \
    -exec yq -N '[{ "name": .name, "age": .age }]' {} + |
yq '{ "persons": . }' >output.yaml
```

Testing with the same set of files as above:

```bash
$ rm output.yaml
$ find . -name example.yaml -type f -exec yq -y -s 'map({ name: .name, age: .age })' {} + | yq -y '{ persons: . }' >output.yaml
```

```bash
$ cat output.yaml
persons:
  - name: Andre
    age: 13
  - name: Joao
    age: 18
```

(Running the command designed for Mike's `yq` generates the same output.)

Note that the ordering of the output depends on the order in which `find` finds the files.

Would you want to sort the output file on e.g. the `name` field, then the following would sort the file in-place (note that I don't know how to do this with Mike Farah's Go-based `yq`):

```bash
yq -i -y '.persons |= sort_by(.name)' output.yaml
```

To sort (in-place) in the reverse order:

```bash
yq -i -y '.persons |= (sort_by(.name) | reverse)' output.yaml
```

---

In comments, the user asks whether one can just append data to an existing file.  This is possible.

The commands below assume that the last thing in `output.yaml` is the end of the `persons` array (so that the command is able to just adds new array entries to it).

Using Andrey's `yq`:

```bash
shopt -s globstar failglob
yq -y -s 'map({ name: .name, age: .age })' ./**/example.yaml >>output.yaml
```

or, with `find`,

```bash
find . -name example.yaml -type f \
    -exec yq -y -s 'map({ name: .name, age: .age })' {} + >>output.yaml
```

Using Mike's `yq`:

```bash
shopt -s globstar failglob
yq -N '[{ "name": .name, "age": .age }]' ./**/example.yaml >>output.yaml
```

or, using `find`:

```bash
find . -name example.yaml -type f \
    -exec yq -N '[{ "name": .name, "age": .age }]' {} + >>output.yaml
```

Comment: kusalananda thankyou for the explanation. But I get error with the above command

Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'y' in -y


I edited my question to show how I was trying to solve this

Comment: @AndreSilva There are a few different tools called `yq` that works differently. In my answer, I mentioned which one I'm using. See also here: https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/#installation

Comment: Thank you so much @Kusalananda, I was able to install yq and it is working. Is this tool legit to use?

Also is it possible with find command to append the array to an existing file instead of creating new file?

Comment: I tried with >>output.yaml but it is not working

Comment: @AndreSilva - Check out my [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/714903/369944) below for a solution that works with basic commands available in effectively all distributions

Comment: @AndreSilva I added stuff. Now the answer uses both Andrey Kislyuk's `yq` and Mike Farah's `yq`.  Both are robust software used in production environments, but I find Mike's `yq` severely lacking in features in general. I will address your other issue about appending data soon.

Comment: @AndreSilva Now added a bit about appending to an existing file as well.

Comment: @Kusalananda. I understand that this appends data to an existing file. But I am not getting the right yaml indentation (for sure something I am doing wrong). But If I create the file previously (lets say I add an attribute before persons)

```code

printf 'city: Edinburgh \n persons:\n' >output.yaml;

``` 

and then add the command 

```code

find . -name example.yaml -type f -exec yq -y -s 'map({ name: .name, age: .age})' {} + >>output.yaml

```

how can I get correct Indentation inside persons array?

Comment: @AndreSilva The output will be a valid YAML with `persons` being an array of names and ages. The YAML format allows for indent-less lists.

Comment: @Kusalananda you are correct the output is a valid yaml file. I am able to get the job done using Andrey's yq

But when running with Mike's tool I get the following error 

```code
Error: unknown command "[{ \"name\": .name, \"age\": .age }]" for "yq
```

Can this be related to the tool's version. I am using
 yq (https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version 4.16.2

Comment: @AndreSilva I see `eval` was made implicit in release "4.18.1", so try `yq -N eval '[{ "name": .name, "age": .age }]' ...`.  I'm using "4.25.1" and can't easily test older releases.

Comment: @Kusalananda  you are correct (once more). It works with eval

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this, but the simplest is probably the [`find`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages//man1/find.1.html) command.

FIrst we create the output file with the new array structure:

```
echo "persons:" > newfile.yaml
```

Next, we want to identify every *file* that matches the filename `example.yaml`, in your target directory (let's call it `/home/user/yaml-files`). This is a basic use case for find, and fairly simple to understand:

```
find /home/user/yaml-files -type f -name example.yaml
```

`find` has a powerful built-in feature to execute shell commands when it finds a match, using the `-exec` and `-execdir` options. `-exec` executes in the same working directory from which you ran `find`, while `-execdir` is a safer option in that the shell command runs *"inside"* the directory in which the match is found. For simplicity, we'll use `-exec`.

We need to search these `example.yaml` files for the lines we want, reformat and append the result to our output file:

```
find /home/user/yaml-files -type f -name example.yaml -exec awk '$1 ~ /^name:|^age:/ {gsub(/name:/,"  - name:",$1); gsub(/age:/,"    age:",$1); print $0}' {} \; | tee -a newfile.yaml
```

The `awk` command in there is searching each `example.yaml` for lines that start with either `name:` or `age:`, with no preceding space or other characters. `gsub` is an `awk` built-in which is useful for string substitution. Here we have 2 `gsub` filters, which we're using to format the matched lines before we print them to `stdout`.

Typically one would use redirection to write output to a file, but with `find -exec` that does get a bit more complicated. When that is the case, the `tee` command is great - it echoes output to the console but also to a file. The `-a` option tells `tee` to *append* to the file, otherwise it would overwrite the file every time and we'd be left with only the results of the last write to the file.

This solution uses only a few commands, which to my knowledge are present on every Linux system you are likely to encounter - there are no special requirements and the code is quite portable.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for files with the specific name `example.yaml`, you can do this very easily. First create a new file with `persons:` and then append all lines starting with `name:` or `age:` from all `example.yaml` files to it:

```
printf 'persons:\n' > personsFile
find /target/directory -name example.yaml -exec grep -E '^(name|age):' {} + >> personsFile
```

If you really need the `-` in front of each `name` entry, and the indentation, you could add it in a second pass:

```
printf 'persons:\n' > personsFile
find /target/directory -name example.yaml -exec grep -E '^(name|age):' {} + >> personsFile
sed -i 's/^name/  - name/; s/^age/    age/' personsFile
```

But if you're really dealing with a structured format like YAML, you should probably look at dedicated tools instead of hacking it like this.

Answer (score -1):

Read `man find xargs grep bash` and do something like:

```
printf "%s\n" "persons:" >newfile
find . -type f -name '*.yaml' -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -r \
        grep -E --no-filename 'name:|age:' >>newfile
```

Note: This code has NOT been tested.

Comment: Does not seem to create an actual YAML array.